# Not able to render ImageField of a model in Django Templets

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

**Models.py**

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    body = models.TextField()
    content_photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='passive_income/',blank=True)
    posted = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True, auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey('blog.Category')
```

**Views.py**

```
def view_post(request, slug):
    return render_to_response('blog/view_post.html', {
        'post': get_object_or_404(Blog, slug=slug)
    })
```

**view_post.html**

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}
{% block head_title %}{{ post.title }}{% endblock %}
{% block title %}{{ post.title }}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <li>{{ post.body }}</li>
    <li>{{ post.content_photo }}</li>
{% endblock %}
```

**My query is that when the URL opens a browser it does not display the image.**

Comment: Why duplicate? The OP has some problem and it looks like he dont know  basics, so we can point him in the right direction.

Comment: @DeepSpace I have already searched and implemented some of the results but all in vain.Can you provide me the link of the exact duplicate question, if it satisfies my query, will surely delete my question from the forum.Thanks for the help.

Comment: @gupta_hargobind The link is right there: `This question already has an answer here:
How to render images on Django template 1 answer`

Comment: @WhoKnows Thanks for the concern and yes this is my first project on Django.

Comment: @gupta_hargobind you got two problems: first you should acces the photo by post.category.content_photo , secondly you had wrong your image tag -it is <img src="{{variable}}"/>

Comment: @Whoknows Thanks, Brother, it worked.
<img src="{{post.content_photo.url}}"/>

Comment: @DeepSpace Should I delete this Question ??